# Marketing Cloud - Does Corporate License include FTP and SFTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp, sftp

as in the question I wonder whether MC Corporate License include FTP and SFTP?
From [this link](https://brandcdn.exacttarget.com/sites/exacttarget/files/editions_comparison_data_sheet_-_marketing_cloud_v2.pdf) is not very clear. Is there an official comparison page between the different licences?
Thanks

Comment: Based on the comparison chart, I will at least not assume Basic has SFTP. When you look at the other features, there is a lack of Automation Studio. And you will have difficulty creating import automation without it. You might still be able to drop large files on FTP and import it manually to a Data Extension, but I don't see as a very useful feature on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each Marketing Cloud BU comes with an "enhanced" (s)FTP connected to it.
Most of my client have corporate editions, we use sFTP for all of them - without that, SFMC would have a rather large feature gap.

Have not seen an edition below corporate in the flesh, and this documentation says "contact your representative": https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_enhanced_ftp_guide.htm&type=5

...but from experience - corporate and above, definite yes.

And to reiterate: I would also be very surprised if lower editions didn't have it.